# how to configure my nginx config file for three apps on the same server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, nginx

hello i have three apps (react,angular & node ) i want to configure my nginx file to have this :
mysite.com for react, mysite.com/admin for angular,pmysite.com/api for node app

```
    #node app
    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_error.log;
    }
    #angular app
    location /admin {
    root /var/www/mysite/backoffice/dist/index.html;
                    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_bo.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_bo.log;
    }
    location ~ \.(aac|m3u8|ts) {
            root /var/www/mysite/media;
    }
    location  /uploads/ {
           root  /var/www/mysite/;
   }
   #react app
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3006;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_react.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_react.log;
    }}
```

/admin not working it redirect to /  any solution ?

Comment: And the problem is.... ?!

Comment: /admin redirect to / (react app)

Answer (score 0):

The `root` path under the `location /admin` block serves as the base path for all the subsequent requests matching that pattern. Looks like you've hardcoded the `/admin` path to serve a single file `/var/www/mysite/backoffice/dist/index.html`.

Try changing it to see if this works:

```
location /admin {
    root /var/www/mysite/backoffice/dist;   # change to this
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_bo.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite_bo.log;
}
```